# What does it mean if a generic structure is type-erased?

Tags: programming-languages

This [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyiterator) states that the generic structure `AnyIterator` is a type-erased iterator of `Element`.

Comment: Type-erasure usually means that the runtime doesnt do type checks on generics for you, even if the compiler can. In java, for example, generic type parameters are erased. Not sure if thats the same as what’s going on here.

Comment: @Ben: Type erasure actually means that type information is not preserved in executable code. Type checking is a different concept and not related to type erasure.

Answer (score 1):

It means that at runtime you will not be able to see what object comes out of
the collection, as that information is removed from the lower-level code that is generated by the compiler.

In your specific instance, it would mean that at runtime an object of type `AnyIterator<Element>` will not be able to tell you what is the exact type of `Element`, unless ofcourse, you (implicitly/explicitly) cast it.